# Mobile State (Up or Down)

Tags: android, iphone, ios, phone-state-listener

I need to know if there is any class or Alarm in android or IOS that tells if the mobile is Down or UP, or just started or restarted. (and for how long!)

i'm creating a logging system, and i need to log the different state of the mobile all along the day.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add send notification from you app (native in iOS and Android) to your remote logging server.

Android as well as iOS have Application life cycle. Which provides you with callback if app is in running state , background , foreground etc.[image]

There is a similar one for [Android](http://static.bada.com/contents/blog/20110901/blog_2.jpg)

The idea is that both of them have singleton for application and they have callbacks for app transition stage

Comment: It's not the Application state that i'm worry about, it's the Mobile itself. what i'm asking for is to know when the Mobile/Phone is shutdown, or restarted. is there anyway i can do that?

Comment: That's a system API. Mobiles use Sandboxing you can't use those API's because they are not available to app developers. You need to have access to system API's to do something like that.

Comment: I guess i have to find some alternative solution other than the APIs that may lead to the same result!